# Convert field object to array of objects with a query for existing documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array of `lessons` that contain `supplementalLessonVideo`, which is an object. I want to now make the field instead be an array called `supplementalLessonVideos` and move the object from `supplementalLessonVideo` into the first index with a query. Not all lessons contain the field either, only some.

Schema:

```
...
lessons: [
  {
    supplementalLessonVideo: 
      {
        videoId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Video" },
        _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
        fieldname: { type: String },
        originalname: { type: String },
        encoding: { type: String },
        mimetype: { type: String },
        filename: { type: String },
        size: { type: Number },
        key: { type: String },
        url: { type: String },
      },
  },
];
```

and I am wanting to make it into:

```
...
lessons:[
    {
 supplementalLessonVideos: 
        [
      {
          videoId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Video" },
          _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
          fieldname: { type: String },
          originalname: { type: String },
          encoding: { type: String },
          mimetype: { type: String },
          filename: { type: String },
          size: { type: Number },
          key: { type: String },
          url: { type: String },
       }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there a query I can write and run on the DB to convert the field to an array and then move the object data into the first index of the array?

So, going from this:

```
    "supplementalLessonVideo" : {
                "videoId" : ObjectId("5ed868ab7c77482170d135f3"), 
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ed868ab7c77482170d135f4"), 
                "fieldname" : "supplemental-lesson-video", 
                "originalname" : "Student Navigation Video April 2018.mp4", 
                "encoding" : "7bit", 
                "mimetype" : "video/mp4", 
                "filename" : "supplemental-lesson-video-1591240848919-741719000", 
                "size" : 15255388, 
                "key" : "supplemental-lesson-video", 
                "url" : "https://vimeo.com"
            },
```

To this:

```
    "supplementalLessonVideos" : [{
                "videoId" : ObjectId("5ed868ab7c77482170d135f3"), 
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ed868ab7c77482170d135f4"), 
                "fieldname" : "supplemental-lesson-video", 
                "originalname" : "Student Navigation Video April 2018.mp4", 
                "encoding" : "7bit", 
                "mimetype" : "video/mp4", 
                "filename" : "supplemental-lesson-video-1591240848919-741719000", 
                "size" : 15255388, 
                "key" : "supplemental-lesson-video", 
                "url" : "https://vimeo.com"
            }],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use. It creates an array and deletes the older object.

```
db.getCollection('test2').update({},[{
    $set: {
            supplementalLessonVideos: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    [], //Creating new array
                    [{ //Adding values from object
                        videoId:"supplementalLessonVideo.videoId",
                        encoding:"supplementalLessonVideo.encoding"                    
                    }]
                ]
                }}          
},

{
    $unset:"supplementalLessonVideo"
}])
```

`updateMany` also works in this case.